# gin-gonic and gorilla/websocket does not propagate message

Tags: go, gorilla

So I made a few changes to this example to make it work with gin-gonic
https://github.com/utiq/go-in-5-minutes/tree/master/episode4

The websocket handshake between many clients is succesful. The problem is that when a client sends a message, the message is not propagated to the rest of the clients.

Comment: Are you able to run the example without any issue? We don't know, what changes you have did to the example? Can you please create a code snippet on play.golang.org with reproducing your issue?

Comment: Yes, I was able to run the example witouth any issue. Changes are in the commit history: https://github.com/utiq/go-in-5-minutes/commit/268f2d3adc8a90b643ff5dfed34205a92d25e6b4#diff-4c44d7542df3ff4221e5fcf36d8ef0b4

Comment: Going through your commit, will get back

Comment: Did you get a chance to verify the answer?

Comment: Hey @jeevatkm thank you so much for your answer. I couldn't check it out because I started working in another feature of the app since I was stuck in that part. I'll check it out tomorrow. In general, I think your change will fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look on your [commit changes](https://github.com/utiq/go-in-5-minutes/commit/268f2d3adc8a90b643ff5dfed34205a92d25e6b4#diff-4c44d7542df3ff4221e5fcf36d8ef0b4) of `episode4`.

**My observations as follows:**

- You're creating `hub` instance on every incoming request at [stream handler](https://github.com/utiq/go-in-5-minutes/blob/master/episode4/connection.go#L52). `hub` instance used to keeps track connections, etc. so you're losing it on every request.
- You have removed index/home handler (may be you wanted to convert to gin handler or something, I don't know).

Now, let's bring `episode4` into action. Please do following changes (as always improve it as you like). I have tested your `episode4` with below changes, it's working fine.

Make `/ws` handler work on `server.go`:

```
h := newHub()
wsh := wsHandler{h: h}
r.GET("/ws", func(c *gin.Context) {
    wsh.ServeHTTP(c.Writer, c.Request)
})
```

Remove the stream handler on `connection.go`:

```
func stream(c *gin.Context) {
    h := newHub()
    wsHandler{h: h}.ServeHTTP(c.Writer, c.Request)
}
```

Adding index HTML handler on `server.go`: (added it to test episode4 at my end)

```
r.SetHTMLTemplate(template.Must(template.ParseFiles("index.html")))
r.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
    c.HTML(200, "index.html", nil)
})
```

Comment: I made the change but I get this error when I try to connect: failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404 Something I'm trying to do is to connect from an AngularJS app, so I call the websocket like this ws = new $WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8085/ws");

Comment: I was able to execute locally with changes mentioned in the answer. Let me send you the PR of episode4 with working state then you can improve it as per your need.

Comment: Awesome!, it was my mistake trying to implement it in a different script. Thanks @jeevatkm!!

Comment: do you have a clue of how to make this "multi rooms"?

Comment: Yes, let's do that conversation on Github or SO chat, but not in this Q&A.